# Switching views in a Silverlight Mvvm application

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I have a View where the user can select "Basic Configuration" and "Advanced Configuration" from a radiobutton group. This view will then display one of two usercontrols (views): BasicConfigurationView and AdvancedConfigurationView. I can solve this by just hiding/showing the views when the user clik on the radiobuttons, but is there a better way? It would have been perfect if the AdvancedConfigurationView was not instantiated at all if the user chose the BasicConfigurationView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Prism or what Microsoft also calls Composite WPF.  With Prism you can dynamically download, instantiate modules (user controls) and inject them into pre-defined regions in your views.

Here is the link.  http://www.codeplex.com/CompositeWPF